How to data bind with pageData?
If I bind directly to data, like:
type Props = {
  data: PageData;
};

let { data }: Props = $props();

<input bind:value={data.product.name} />

I get the following warning:

[svelte] binding_property_non_reactivebind:value={data.product.name} (src/routes/...) is binding to a non-reactive property

if I destructure as $state(), like:
type Props = {
  data: PageData;
};

let { data }: Props = $props();
let { product } = $state(data);

<input bind:value={product.name} />

the warning is gone, but then i lose reactivity when the data prop changes..
How can I bind, and not lose reactivity?

Svelte needs instruction that data can be bound and may be reactive in the child-to-parent direction. This can be accomplished by using the $bindable() rune.
type Props = {
  data: PageData;
};

let { data = $bindable() }: Props = $props();

<input bind:value={data.product.name} />

